# password failing after updating windows 8 virtual machine

Tags: windows-8, updates, password-protection

I have a hyper v with a virtual machine.
That virtual machine just did updates and now my password isn't working.
The language isn't changed.

Comment: This isn't a programming related question

Answer (score 0):

Change keyboard layout.
Try entering your password with on-screen keyboard.